# Matching multiple overlapping n-grams with a single regular expression

Tags: python, regex, search, nlp, n-gram

I am trying to perform regular expressions to match multiple n-grams in a document. 
I first get a list of n-grams, I compile them into a regex like so:

```
sNgrams = '|'.join(('\s+'.join(re.escape(gram) for gram in nGram.split())) for nGram in aNgrams)
```

(Splitting the n-grams to tokens on any whitespace character, re.escape these tokens and join them with '\s+'-es (so I can match the ngrams over newlines, double spaces, tabs and whatnot), and then join the n-grams with '|' for the regex)

My regex looks like this:

```
reNgram = re.compile('(\A|\W+)(' + sNgrams + ')(?=\W+|\Z)',flags=re.UNICODE|re.IGNORECASE)
```

Now, this works fine for most cases, however, when an n-gram overlaps with another one, only one match is found:

```
doc = 'aap noot mies'

aNgrams = ['aap','noot','aap noot']
sNgrams = 'aap|noot|aap\\s+noot'
re.findall(reNgram,doc)
[('', 'aap'), (' ', 'noot')]

aNgrams = ['mies','aap noot']
re.findall(reNgram,doc)
[('', 'aap noot'), (' ', 'mies')]
```

- Is there any way to solve this? To return all (sub)strings that match
  in the document?
- Furthermore, speed/efficiency is of high importance
  (I'm firing tens of thousands of these regexes), is there anything I
  can do to optimize? I've read that pre-compiling the regexes doesn't
  do much, as the 'on-the-fly' compiled regexes are cached anyway, are there any (other) obvious steps I can take to speed up these expressions?

Comment: So you would have liked `'aap noot'` as an additional match in your first example, but the second example is correct?

Comment: Uhh you're right, that 2nd example doesn't really clear things up, yes, I'd like the first one to match all three.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with a single regex.

You can get a bit closer by

- using lookahead assertions to find at least those overlapping matches that don't start at the same position
- sorting your n-grams descendingly by length to ensure the larger matches are found first

Now, actual overlapping matches (`noot` starts after `app noot`) can be found:

```
>>> sNgrams = '|'.join(('\s+'.join(re.escape(gram) 
...                    for gram in nGram.split())) 
...                    for nGram in reversed(sorted(aNgrams, key=len)))
>>> sNgrams
'aap\\s+noot|noot|aap'
>>> reNgrams = re.compile(r"(?<!\w)(?=(" + sNgrams + r")(?!\w))",
...                         flags=re.UNICODE|re.IGNORECASE)
>>> reNgrams.findall(doc)
['aap noot', 'noot']
```

But it still can't find both `aap` and `aap noot`. A regex can only report one match per position in the string, so it has to match one of the two.

For a way around that, you would have to split your list of n-grams into lists where none of the strings start with identical words, and apply those regexes sequentially. I suspect that that's not going to be very performant, but I don't see any other way (besides checking each word in its own regex, and that's not going to be very fast either).

Comment: Okay, that's about what I suspected. Thanks for your answer. Indeed, I was thinking about sorting on length and/or splitting up the n-gram lists in such a way that no overlapping words would occur. I might look into that now. When it comes to speed, I am going to attempt to use esmre (https://github.com/wharris/esmre), Not sure what kind of difference that will make, but it's worth a shot.